# Android - Picasa Upload Image

Tags: android, upload, picasa

I want to connect to Picasa and upload a picture (let's assume I already have a reference to the image).
How can I do? If possible let's the user choose user and pass to login.
I tried some example but they fails or give error.
If someone already tested some example can link it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to see this open source [project](http://code.google.com/p/picasaphotouploader/) you can find some useful resources

Comment: thank you (even if i already found it, it seems a little big as sample :P)